# We decided that if they do not leave the place in one day, we would surely force them out. To use 'do not' or 'did not' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, tenses, speech, indirect-speech, narration

> We decided that if they *do not* leave the place in one day, we would surely force them out.
> We decided that if they *did not* leave the place in one day, we would surely force them out.

Difference between using 'do not' and 'did not' in the above sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second sentence is idiomatic and is speaking about the past. Presumably they have now left. Perhaps it all happened a while ago.

The first sentence might be:

> We decided that if they do not leave the place in one day we *will*
> surely force them out.

or:

> We *have* decided that if they do not leave the place in one day we
> *will* surely force them out.

In both, the decision was made today: crunch time is tomorrow.

Rather than "in one day", we [UK] would generally say, "in one day's time". Leaving the place "*in one day*" focuses on the duration of the actual leaving-process; which forcing them out wouldn't hasten.

**NOTE**: *Greybeard's answer and Peter Shor's comments below suggest there are differences between US and UK usage I didn't know about.*

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointing out the mistakes.  Based on answers of  GreyBeard and Old Brixtonian, I think I can have the sentences updated as: "We have decided that if they do not leave the place in one day's time, we will surely force them out" and  "We decided that if they did not leave the place in one day's time, we would surely force them out".

Comment: I have on more doubt: Difference between "We had decided..." and "We decided...", when we discuss something about what happened in the past.

Comment: "In one day's time" might be a British English thing.  It doesn't sound natural to me as an American, and I would just say "in one day".

Comment: Thanks nsach for your comment

Answer (score 2):

> We decided that if they do not leave the place in one day, we would surely force them out.

Spoken after the decision but before they have left -> They have not left yet.

> We decided that if they did not leave the place in one day, we would surely force them out.

Spoken a long time after the decision and describing past events whose result is known.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but "if they _do_ not leave... we _would_ surely force them out..." sounds unnatural to me.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: It sounds perfectly natural to me. But I suspect that in the 19th century, among educated speakers, the first answer would have been the only acceptable one. And in different dialects the grammar is presumably changing at different speeds.

Comment: Thanking @Greybeard also. Wish I could accept his answer also.

Comment: Thanks, Greybeard and @Peter Shor. I've added a footnote to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is fine. 'We **decided** that if they **did not** leave the place in one day, we **would** surely force them out.' It refers to the past. (do not ➜ did not, will ➜ would)

We can say 'We **have decided** that if they **do not** leave the place in one day, we **will** surely force them out'. The sentence 'We have decided' is in the present perfect. So we use 'do not' and 'will'. (NOT 'did not' and 'would')

'We **have decided** that if they **do not** leave the place in one day, we **will** surely force them out' means that they have not left yet, but the decision has been made (by us)

We decided- simple past tense

We have decided- present perfect tense

We use the simple past tense to talk about the past. We use the present perfect tense to talk about the past and the present.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the conversation *"What did you decide at the meeting?"*  *"We decided that if they do not leave the place in one day we will surely force them out."* And in fact, you probably wouldn't use the present perfect there, because the meeting is in the past, even though the leaving and forcing out are in the future. There is no rule in English that all the verbs in a sentence have to agree in tense, even if are set at different times.

Comment: Peter Shor, 'There is absolutely nothing wrong with the conversation "What did you decide at the meeting?' - I agree with you. But 'We decided that if they do not leave the place in one day we will surely force them out.' - I don't agree with you. To me, 'We have decided that if they do not leave the place in one day we will surely force them out.' is correct. past simple- What did you decide this morning. (It is afternoon or evening.) present perfect-What have you decided this morning? (It is still morning.)